# Is there a way to store a large JSON object in a database so it can be accessed quicker than reading (and parsing) it from disk (SSD/RAMDISK)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, redis

I have several JSON data files (complex objects) around ~200MB each.
I need to have their data readable in several node.js workers in parallel.

Putting them on a RAMDISK and doing fs.readFile + JSON.parse yields ~3.1 sec read/parse time per file.
How can I store this data so the node.js workers can access them faster?

I tried Redis/Memcached/MongoDB/etc... by breaking the data up in smaller chunks and reading/parsing them individually but it actually takes longer than reading from the file. (e.g. MongoDB needs 8.6 seconds querying it from 16MB chunks)

There surely has to be some kind of JSON/hash-oriented database that performs better than simply reading JSON data from disk and parsing it?

I thought I can read the data in one node.js process, fork a child-worker, and access it from there, but apparently threads forked by node.js have isolated memory space.

#### Is there a way to store a large (~200MB) JSON object in an in-memory-database (like Redis/MongoDB/Memcached) so it can be accessed as a whole quicker than reading (and parsing) it from a RAMDISK?

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
|        Storage      |          Method          | Time to Object |
+---------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| .json on SSD/RAMDISK| fs.readFile & JSON.parse |     3.1 sec    |
| Redis string        | db.get & JSON.parse      |     4.5 sec    |
| MongoDB 16MB chunks | col.find({_id:$in: ids}) |     8.6 sec    |
+---------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Since you are already have the files in memory, on a ramdisk, loading them is pretty quick. Doing the same from a database, be it sql, nosql, disk based with heavy striping, mem based, ... a database does have overhead. It enables you to have concurrency and/or indexing. You gain performance by getting only what you need.

Comment: I would think Redis would be even faster than RAMDISK, since there wouldn't be the overhead of FS calls. Also, Redis keys can be up to 512MB in size, so not sure why you would need to break into 16MB chunks.

Comment: @CarlZulauf You propose storing the whole 200MB parsed JSON object as a one key - one hash value in Redis? (16MB chunks were only created to store them in MongoDB, max. limit for BSON serialization)

Comment: @CarlZulauf Redis does not support storing complex JSON objects. I would also have to serialize it and store it as a string/parse it upon retrieval (~4.5 seconds)

Comment: Have you tried Materialized Paths? Might be a good idea to store chunks in mongodb and only use the needed part of the large object. There is an article explaining this method here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/